# How does newrelic_rpm send data to New Relic server?

Tags: newrelic

We are using newrelic_rpm in production environment.

I changed the log level to debug.
Whenever agent sends data to servers it displays:

```
[11/08/11 13:58:09 +0530 mubarocks.local (788)] DEBUG : Sending data to New Relic Service
[11/08/11 13:58:09 +0530 mubarocks.local (788)] DEBUG : Spool file empty.
[11/08/11 13:58:09 +0530 mubarocks.local (788)] DEBUG : Connect to newrelic.com:80/agent_listener/8/.../metric_data?run_id=327878253
[11/08/11 13:58:09 +0530 mubarocks.local (788)] DEBUG : Http Connection opened to 204.93.223.142:80
[11/08/11 13:58:10 +0530 mubarocks.local (788)] DEBUG : Uncompressed content returned
[11/08/11 13:58:10 +0530 mubarocks.local (788)] DEBUG : 2011-11-08 13:58:09 +0530: sent 8 timeslices (327878253) in 0.660168 seconds
```

It doesn't show actual data being sent.

How can I log actual data which is being sent to server?

How can I debug the data format?

Answer (score 4):

Tracing the call stack, you need to look at the source of the gem.

```
 lib/new_relic/agent/agent.rb
```

The data is actually send by a `Net::HTTP::Post`

```
 def send_request(opts)
   request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(opts[:uri],
     'CONTENT-ENCODING' => opts[:encoding],
     'HOST' => opts[:collector].name)
   request.content_type = "application/octet-stream"
   request.body = opts[:data]

   log.debug "Connect to #{opts[:collector]}#{opts[:uri]}"

   ...
```

But, by the point the data arrives here, it's compressed.

```
def invoke_remote(method, *args)
  #determines whether to zip the data or send plain
  post_data, encoding = compress_data(args)

  response = send_request({
    :uri => remote_method_uri(method),
    :encoding => encoding,
    :collector => collector,
    :data => post_data})

  ...
```

So `compress_data` is a good place to look.

So lets add an initializer that adds log statements whenever the data is sent.

```
module NewRelic
  module Agent
    class Agent
      def compress_data_with_debug(object)
        Rails.logger.debug("Newrelic Data: #{object.inspect}")

        compress_data_without_debug(object)
      end

      alias_method_chain :compress_data, :debug
    end
  end
end
```

And that should get you somewhere decent to start with.

Answer (score 0):

New Relic now supports an [audit log](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/manage-apm-agents/configuration/log-audit-all-data-your-new-relic-agent-transmits), enabling all data that is transmitted by the app to be logged in human-readable format.